# Excel Formula IF(AND?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm trying to write a formula that will look at Column A and match the 2 digit letter code to a linked spreadsheet in Column G:G and if they match check to make sure a certain text phrase is there, if so grab and input the date from the Cell in  B. 
For example:

[image: Caption1]

Column A has the Prefix PA, In column K I have the current formula

`=IF(AND(A2='[Fall19 Schedule Demo.xlsx]Ashro'!G:G, '[Fall19 Schedule Demo.xlsx]Ashro'!B:B="Final Retail Review by MBD"),'[Fall19 Schedule Demo.xlsx]Ashro'!$C$30,"No")`

The idea is, it looks at column A2 and if that = the PA in Column G from caption 2

[image: Caption2]

Then it will look at column B and make sure it also says "Final Retail Review by MBD" and if so it will place the date from Column C (In this case 5/9/2019) otherwise it will say "No".

The problem is that even though this criteria is met my formula doesn't seem to want to pull the date, and I'm not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I'm sure there is an easier way to do this that I'm not thinking of so I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks!!!
-Deke

Comment: Use VLOOKUP with IFERROR to get required column from Fall19 Schedule Demo file. In IFERROR just return 0 for false value inside AND

Comment: A2='[Fall19 Schedule Demo.xlsx]Ashro'!G:G IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, G:G, column number in selection, 0), 0) in this case your selection is G:G so column number can only be 1. But, let's say you want to grab from H column, then selection of G:H and column number 2 would do the trick. In your current code, you are not claiming any data from G:G selection

Comment: I had considered using a vlookup, the problem I have is this would use a negative number and in my experience vlookups don't like using a negative for the column selection. Have you been able to get that to work? cause this would be a -5 and currently it doesn't work.

Comment: Right, I thought it is possible to move G column data to A column and do work from there. Anyway, happy to see that you got the solution.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I have to keep the current format, Otherwise I'd have made more changes. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `COUNTIFS()` to find if it exists:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('[Fall19 Schedule Demo.xlsx]Ashro'!G:G,A2,'[Fall19 Schedule Demo.xlsx]Ashro'!B:B,"Final Retail Review by MBD"),'[Fall19 Schedule Demo.xlsx]Ashro'!$C$30,"No")
```

On note trying to match on a long string may return false negatives, in that it is looking at a letter for letter match and if there is a misspelling or added spaces then it will return `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks this put me on the right track! Appreciate the help!